# how to pass data from component to service?

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a tasks.component.ts file in that the code is

```
addTask($event: Event) {
      alert(this.name);

      var newTask ={
      name: this.name
     }

//alert(this.tasks.push(newTask));

 this.taskServices.addTask(newTask)
    .subscribe(tasks => {
    this.tasks.push(tasks);
   });

  }
```

task.services.ts
this is my taskservices file..in that i write

```
 addTask(newTask){
 var headers = new Headers();
 headers.append('ContentType','application/json');
 return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/edata',JSON.stringify(newTask)).map(res => res.json());
 }
```

i am trying to pass the data 'this.tasks.push(tasks);' it should pass data to
addTask(newTask){...}  which is in task.services.ts

but it was not pushing the data to the addTask(){...} how to do that ,is there any wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make `newtask` variable as component level and need to provide provider and access that newTask method as shown below :

```
export class TasksComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
      newTask;

      constructor(private _taskService:taskService) { }

        addTask($event: Event) {
          alert(this.name);

          this.newTask ={
          name: this.name
         }

        this._taskService.addTask(this.newTask);


        ngOnInit() {
             this.taskServices.addTask(newTask)
                .subscribe(tasks => {
                this.tasks.push(tasks);
               });
        }
    }
```